# Bullet points not showing when fading in an <li> in FF

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firefox

http://jsfiddle.net/mnbayazit/P5Hjn/

When I try to fade in an `<li>` the bullet point isn't showing up. Works fine in Chrome, sorta works in IE but the bullet point shows up only after it's fully faded in, and just doesn't work at all in FF 3.6. Is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('button').click(function() {
    $('<li>item</li>').hide().appendTo('ul').fadeIn().css('display', '');
    return false;
});
```

The call to `fadeIn()` add `display: block;` to the style of the `<li>` element which seems to not be well handled.

Comment: Well basically the default value of `display` for a `<li>` element is **list-item**. When `hide()` and `fadeIn()` replace it by _none_ or _block_ I suppose Firefox decides that it's not a 'list item' anymore. Replacing `.css('display', '')` by `.css('display', 'list-item')` in the above code would have the same effect.